# Assigning existing document to variable in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to assign an existing document to a variable which I can open and activate later. There might be several documents open when running the code (including the document containing the VBA project) so I need make sure I'm activating the right one.

The below doesn't work because I need the filename and not the file-path in the final line, but I don't know how to extract this from the path in line 2...

```
Dim NewQuote1 as string
Set NewQuote1 ="C:\Library\doc1.docx"
Documents.Open fileName:=NewQuote1
...
Documents(NewQuote1).Activate
```

Comment: You can use filesystemobject to get the filename property you're looking for. Couple good examples showing how to use it at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/05/30/how-can-i-extract-just-the-file-name-from-the-full-path-to-the-file/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not up on my Word VBA, but I'm pretty sure it'll be very similar to Excel.

So:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrdDoc As Document
    Dim NewQuote1 As String

    NewQuote1 = "C:\Library\doc1.docx"

    Set wrdDoc = Documents.Open(NewQuote1)

    'You can now reference the document using wrdDoc.
    wrdDoc.Activate

    MsgBox wrdDoc.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: that's very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Just noticed in your question that you talk about the document containing the VBA project - this document can always be referenced using `ThisDocument`, so `ThisDocument.Activate`, `Msgbox ThisDocument.Name`, etc.